# Does pytest restrict ALL lowercase options from custom command line arguments?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to port some command line arguments from an `argparse.ArgumentParser` instance into the equivalent pytest `conftest.py` file using pytest's `pytest_addoption`

Looking at the pytest help function I find 12 used single character short options, namely `k, m, x, c, s, v, q, r, l, h, p, o`

```
MacBook-Pro:~ user$ pytest --help | grep " -[a-z]"
  -k EXPRESSION         only run tests which match the given substring
                        -k 'test_method or test_other' matches all test
                        'test_method' or 'test_other', while -k 'not
  -m MARKEXPR           only run tests matching given mark expression.
                        example: -m 'mark1 and not mark2'.
  -x, --exitfirst       exit instantly on first error or failed test.
  -c file               load configuration from `file` instead of trying to
  -s                    shortcut for --capture=no.
  -v, --verbose         increase verbosity.
  -q, --quiet           decrease verbosity.
  -r chars              show extra test summary info as specified by chars
  -l, --showlocals      show locals in tracebacks (disabled by default).
  -h, --help            show help message and configuration info
  -p name               early-load given plugin (multi-allowed). To avoid
  -o [OVERRIDE_INI [OVERRIDE_INI ...]], --override-ini=[OVERRIDE_INI [OVERRIDE_INI ...]]
```

And yet if I attempt to define an option outside that set I get the following exception

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('-b', '--build_special' )


  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/argparsing.py", line 72, in addoption
    self._anonymous.addoption(*opts, **attrs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/argparsing.py", line 305, in addoption
    self._addoption_instance(option, shortupper=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/argparsing.py", line 315, in _addoption_instance
    raise ValueError("lowercase shortoptions reserved")
ValueError: lowercase shortoptions reserved
```

This seems to be the case no matter the character I choose which is making me think this is just restricted behavior period.

**Question: does pytest restrict any and all uses of short options?**

---

I'm a bit baffled because when you look at the relevant pytest [source](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/config/argparsing.py#L60)

```
def addoption(self, *opts, **attrs):
    """ register a command line option.
    :opts: option names, can be short or long options.
    :attrs: same attributes which the ``add_option()`` function of the
       `argparse library
       <http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html>`_
       accepts.
    After command line parsing options are available on the pytest config
    object via ``config.option.NAME`` where ``NAME`` is usually set
    by passing a ``dest`` attribute, for example
    ``addoption("--long", dest="NAME", ...)``.
    """
    self._anonymous.addoption(*opts, **attrs)
```

it seems to suggest I can use the exact same syntax as argparse's add_option, which interestingly enough in the argparse [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#upgrading-optparse-code) mentions that

> Replace all `optparse.OptionParser.add_option()` calls with
>   `ArgumentParser.add_argument()` calls.

and the add_argument [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags) explicitly lists this single flag option as allowed:

> The `add_argument()` method must know whether an optional argument,
>   like `-f` or `--foo`, or a positional argument, like a list of
>   filenames, is expected. The first arguments passed to add_argument()
>   must therefore be either a series of flags, or a simple argument name.
>   For example, an optional argument could be created like:
>
> `>>> parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the pytest source code...

### [/src/_pytest/config/argparsing.py](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/322190fd84e1b86d7b9a2d71f086445ca80c39b3/src/_pytest/config/argparsing.py#L362-L369)

```
def _addoption_instance(self, option: "Argument", shortupper: bool = False) -> None:
    if not shortupper:
        for opt in option._short_opts:
            if opt[0] == "-" and opt[1].islower():
                raise ValueError("lowercase shortoptions reserved")
    if self.parser:
        self.parser.processoption(option)
    self.options.append(option)
```

Yes they restrict all lowercase short options